# Laptop Usage on Airplanes

Tags: internet-connection, laptop-mode

- Do I require a mobile stick?
- Is there an in flight type wireless connection to be online?
- Can I plug my laptop in on the plane if my battery won't last?

Comment: oh flying from B.C to Dublin Ireland

Answer (score 1):

**Mobile networks:** A mobile stick won't help you because you certainly won't have reception when flying.

**In-flight WiFi:** If your flight has WiFi or not depends on your airline. I suggest checking with them per telephone or looking into the flight details. Chances are you won't have WiFi as it's not that common yet.

**Power outlets:** Most airlines don't have power outlets in the economy class, or at least not for every seat. Business class passengers will most certainly have outlets. But their type can vary between DC outlets (like those found in cars) or AC outlets. [See here](http://www.seatguru.com/articles/in-seat_laptop_power.php) for more details. In any case, check with the airline. They will be able to tell you which outlets are available. Depending on the type of outlet they offer you will need a matching connector.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you either ring the airline or look on their website to see what plane you will be flying and then take a look at [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/).

If you can't find the information, pretty much all (long haul) business/premium class have plugs, but the majority of the time you need to either buy a special adapter or ask the steward/stewardess to borrow one.

The only economy I have been in where they gave one was on Emirates (IMHO best airline ever!).

As for mobile stick - it is *possible* they will work when over land and/or short distance from land, however, most likely, the flight will either not allow them (safety reasons) or have a local Femtocell and charge a fortune for roaming in it.

For in-flight Wifi, this is usually the best bet, but again, it can be pricey (although a lot of airlines do a deal like £10 for an entire flight).... I personally like a flight to actually disconnect me and I try to read or just catch up with sleep!... Also, a lot of airlines that have Wifi usually have a good entertainment system and once you start watching movies, you don't always want to browse the internet!

Comment: truly great answer never heard anyone say u could buy time online on a flight and never heard of that webpage u mentioned ..... my fiance an i talk a lot but i use magicjack as it goes with anywhere and i ca call anywhere from anywhere but need connection to internet and just hook in your old analog phone or apply your majk to your cell but still need connection... so i figured just use msn less and see ea other ,not one to sleep but 2ice a week hyper-insomnia.less i wana do horse I'll never sleep like normal folk since born...lol oh fun-not